# Looking for a list of methods that cause Android API 23 (Marshmallow) to throw the permission needed SecurityException

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

Has the Android team posted a list of methods that cause Android API 23 (Marshmallow) to throw a `SecurityException` when a permission is needed?

Something like:
`RECORD_AUDIO` throws `SecurityException` on the following methods:
  `SpeechRecognizer.startListening`
  etc.

As of now, we're just wandering around our app trying to best-guess when this will happen. Some devices are throwing this exception when others aren't -- as well as the emulator.

EDIT:
Issue solved. This is a problem with Xamarin Studio as it does not flag function calls that need a permissions check. I recently created a project in Android Studio and it red-underlines function calls that need a permissions check.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. I want a list of functions that cause the SecurityException if you don't request a permission on Marshmallow. Stop voting it down if you don't answer correctly.